# R if string contains number,spaces,etc

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to check if a string in R has this format

```
NNNN__NNN
```

i.e. four numbers (N stands for any number [0,9]), two underscores, 3 numbers.

Any help?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried the help for `grep`?

Comment: `N` does not stand for "number" when searching text strings. It is the letter N, Please be specific and post a reproducible example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grepl("\\d{4}__\\d{3}","1234__12reg3")
```

returns False

```
grepl("\\d{4}__\\d{3}","1234__123")
```

returns True

\d is digits in Regex. You should check out ?grepl